# _ * usage is scala pattern matching

Tags: regex, scala

I am bit confused with _ * usage in the below example.It is behaving differently and I am completely  lost in figuring this out .

```
val p1="scala".r
val p2="([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*|[.][0-9]+)$".r

"scala" match {case p1(_) => true case _  => false } // return false


"scala" match {case p1(_ *) => true case _  => false }  // return true

"9" match {case p2(_) => true case _ => false} // return true
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `match` needs a capture group in the pattern. With `_ *` , you ignore this requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `match` needs at least one capture group in the pattern because you are using `case(_)`. This is because "match-case" uses `unapplySeq(target: Any): Option[List[String]]`, which returns the capture group values, and you require 1 captured value to be present with `_`. With `_ *` , you ignore this requirement. See [Scala regex reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.matching.Regex):

> **To check only whether the Regex matches, ignoring any groups, use a *sequence wildcard***:
>
> `"2004-01-20" match {
>     case date(_*) => "It's a date!"
>   }`

Your `p2` contains a capturing group, hence the last line returns true.

Your `p1` does not contain a capturing group, hence the first `match` fails.  The second does not since you disabled this requirement with `*`.

As an alternative, you can use `case p1()` with your first line (the `_` representing the obligatory first capture group is removed here), and it will work, too:

```
"scala" match {case p1() => true case _  => false }) // return true
```

See this [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/t7PdFp)

Comment: I have updated the answer with more explanations and a sample demo.

Comment: incr 1 for IDEONE - never heard of it before that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much